# Xamarin MaterialDesignControlsPlugin MaterialSliderControl not rendering correctly on Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, material-design

I am using this [package](https://github.com/HorusSoftwareUY/MaterialDesignControlsPlugin/blob/develop/MaterialSliderControl.md) in my Xamarin Android app (this problem does not occur on iOS) but am not able to get the slider control to render correctly. It has a property called ActiveTrackColor which is the colour of the track to the left of the thumb. When I interact with it in my app, the track follows the thumb correctly, but when a page initially loads and I set the value in the constructor of the control (either in XAML or in code-behind/view model), the thumb moves to the correct position, but the track colour does not update behind it.

This is what it looks like when the page loads:
[image: on start]

This is what it's supposed to look like:
[image: after I move it manually]

I did find a sketchy workaround doing this  `_ = Task.Delay(600).ContinueWith((t) => { slider.Value = value; });` which gives the page enough time to load before setting the value, but I would much rather find a proper way of doing this.